# Can't update hook_theme after clearing the cache

Tags: 7, hooks

I have a hook_theme instance in my template.php which outputs various components in my theme. I want to add an extra argument to one of the templates but no matter what I do it doesn't update. I have cleared the cache (using drush and not), removed the theme array, cleared cache and added back in. I have even truncated all the cache tables - but somehow it's still picking up the old function. Is there something stupid I have missed?

**template.php**

```
function MYTHEME_theme() {
  return array(

    'featured_blocks' => array(
      'arguments' => array(
        'blocks' => NULL,
        'image_format' => 'test!',
      ),
      'template' => 'featured-blocks',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'MYTHEME') . '/templates/other'
    ),

  );
}
```

**featured-blocks.tpl.php**

```
<?php

printr($blocks); // blocks are all here
print $image_format; // this is undefined!!!
```

**Calling the hook theme**

```
<?php print theme('featured_blocks', array(
            'blocks' => $wrap->field_my_blocks,
            'image_format' => 'this is a test'
          )) ?>
```

Comment: You need to disable the module, and re/enable it.

Comment: What module? This is in my theme's template.php

Comment: in template.php, try `public` before function MY_THEME();

Comment: @ReesGargi I can't see how that work. Results in an error.

Comment: does it get updated if you clear all your code in template?

Comment: Are you sure you're in the right theme folder? Maybe you have multiple dev servers for testing purposes, are you sure you're in the correct server?

Comment: The idea of @ReesGargi was checking if that would cause a WSOD, or an exception being printed. If that happened, it meant the theme was the currently set theme, and Drupal caught the change.

Comment: If putting 'public' result in an error that means your code is running. run cron and check your watchlog

Comment: After doing a bit more reading I restarted my MAMP server and switched themes, then back again. I'm not sure which did it but it's working now... Annoying that this caused me hours of grief

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit more reading I restarted my MAMP server and switched themes, then back again. I'm not sure which did it but it's working now...

Comment: did you mentioned it was a MAMP server? Drupal is weird on localhost